# No source TO compile maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile in Linux System

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins-pipeline, maven-2

I am trying to run my selenium tessts from a linux system where Jenkins is configured . But On running the job i am getting No sources to compile message @ maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile section .
Note : It is a Maven Project.

pom.xml contenet

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    Aspire_TA_Aspire_Generic_Framework_Java
    GenericFramework_Java
    1.0.0
    jar

```
<name>Aspire TA Aspire Generic Framework - Java</name>
<url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>


<dependencies>

            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.4</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>

                <!-- <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <url>${project.url}</url>
                    <site>${site}</site>
                </systemPropertyVariables> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <!-- To directly pointing the saucelabs repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>saucelabs-repository</id>
        <url>https://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- To directly pointing the soapui maven2 repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Below is my Directory structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Linux is a case-sensitive OS by default, so you should rename the 'src/test/Java' folder to be 'src/test/java', and I don't see a 'src/main/java' folder so it has nothing to compile, or you should use the following configuration in your pom.xml file:

```
<build>
    ...
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/Java</testSourceDirectory>
    ...
</build>
```